# geopandas.explore, marker size according to score

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

Is there any way to increase the size of the marker dots according to `score` value?
Haven't found one for the `explore()` function, but maybe there is a workaround?

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------+
|    |   Score |   LATITUDE |   LONGITUDE | Name   | geometry                       |
|----+---------+------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------|
|  0 |       9 |    47.1989 |     6.51907 | a      | POINT (6.51906939 47.19885642) |
|  1 |       4 |    47.1993 |     6.52133 | a      | POINT (6.52133392 47.19932583) |
|  2 |      12 |    47.2006 |     6.52169 | a      | POINT (6.521687 47.20058986)   |
|  3 |      12 |    47.2006 |     6.52169 | a      | POINT (6.521687 47.20058986)   |
|  4 |       2 |    47.1985 |     6.51926 | b      | POINT (6.51926344 47.19847967) |
|  5 |       4 |    47.1998 |     6.52126 | b      | POINT (6.52126031 47.19980364) |
|  6 |       2 |    47.1993 |     6.52197 | b      | POINT (6.52197033 47.19929947) |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

[image]

### MWE

```
import geopandas
import pandas as pd

dict_data = {'Score': {0: 9, 1: 4, 2: 12, 3: 12, 4: 2, 5: 4, 6: 2},
 'LATITUDE': {0: 47.19885642,
  1: 47.19932583,
  2: 47.20058986,
  3: 47.20058986,
  4: 47.19847967,
  5: 47.19980364,
  6: 47.19929947},
 'LONGITUDE': {0: 6.51906939,
  1: 6.52133392,
  2: 6.521687,
  3: 6.521687,
  4: 6.51926344,
  5: 6.52126031,
  6: 6.52197033},
 'Name': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, 
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df["LONGITUDE"], df["LATITUDE"]))

gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

gdf.explore(
    column="Name",
    tiles="CartoDB positron",
    cmap="viridis_r"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- this was added to **geopandas** 0.11 [explore](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore). `style_function`
- have just committed a PR to further enhance capability [#2572](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2572)
- with a simple `lambda` function this can be done:

```
    style_kwds={"style_function":lambda x: {"radius":x["properties"]["Score"]}
```

- the `Score` column becomes a **geojson** property that is accessed for each point

#### full code

```
import geopandas
import pandas as pd

dict_data = {'Score': {0: 9, 1: 4, 2: 12, 3: 12, 4: 2, 5: 4, 6: 2},
 'LATITUDE': {0: 47.19885642,
  1: 47.19932583,
  2: 47.20058986,
  3: 47.20058986,
  4: 47.19847967,
  5: 47.19980364,
  6: 47.19929947},
 'LONGITUDE': {0: 6.51906939,
  1: 6.52133392,
  2: 6.521687,
  3: 6.521687,
  4: 6.51926344,
  5: 6.52126031,
  6: 6.52197033},
 'Name': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, 
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df["LONGITUDE"], df["LATITUDE"]))

gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

gdf.explore(
    column="Name",
    tiles="CartoDB positron",
    cmap="viridis_r",
    style_kwds={"style_function":lambda x: {"radius":x["properties"]["Score"]}}
)
```

[image]